# Filter where on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this table

```
User        | SecretId | Status
warheat1990 |     NULL |    REV
warheat1990 |     NULL |    COM
warheat1990 |        1 |    REV
warheat1990 |        1 |    COM
```

I want to filter out data with (Status = REV and SecretId IS NOT NULL combined) so the final result will be

```
User        | SecretId | Status
warheat1990 |     NULL |    REV
warheat1990 |     NULL |    COM
warheat1990 |        1 |    COM
```

My query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE User = 'warheat1990' AND (Status <> 'REV' AND SecretId IS NULL)
```

but it's not working because it gives me only this ROW.

```
User        | SecretId | Status
warheat1990 |     NULL |    COM
```

So how do I exclude data with Status = REV but only if SecretId IS NOT NULL

I feel stupid that I can't figure out this simple case. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In your expected result shouldn't last row be `warheat1990 |  1 | REM`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use OR in your SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE User = 'warheat1990' AND (Status <> 'REV' OR SecretId IS NULL)
```

Here is the math knowledge: you want to match the condition "not (A and B)", then you can use the equivalent expression ((not A) or (not B)), so you should use OR instead of AND.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to return data where `Status <> 'REV'` **OR** `SecretId IS NULL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE User = 'warheat1990' AND 
    (Status <> 'REV' OR SecretId IS NULL)
```

When you are using `AND` you get only those rows that satisfy both conditions. When you are using `OR` you get the rows that match at least one criteria.

Answer (score 2):

So you want select all, except for (Status = REV and SecretId IS NOT NULL) ?

We have: NOT (Status = REV and SecretId IS NOT NULL)  <=>  (Status <> REV or  SecretId IS NULL)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE User = 'warheat1990' AND (Status <> 'REV' or SecretId IS NULL)
```